# Should I allow my 19 year old son to sleep during the day?

Tags: sleep, teen, video-games

My son is 19 years old, he is a computer science student and has just finished college and is awaiting his grades. In September he will be going to University if he gets the needed grades which he is predicted to easily achieve.

He has a part-time job where he works 30 hours a week but apart from that he spends most of his time at his PC or asleep, with the occasional night out maybe once a month.

Should I enforce being awake between the normal hours, or is it OK that he plays video games at night and sleeps during the day (apart from when at work)?

Currently I have been turning off the WiFi at night to try and force him to be awake at normal times which he really dislikes.

Comment: Man I miss the days when I could sleep whenever I wanted, stay up if I wanted... I wouldn't react at all to it unless he gets his grades then proceeds to do absolutely nothing. If indeed he does get some job using his degree he will have to adjust his schedule, the work work work... and after a decade he might think back longingly to the days when something simple like staying up at night and sleeping during the day were possible. And hopefully when he dreams of a life absent of the crushing nightmare of employment he wont think about how much he wasn't allowed to do.

Comment: Is he _napping_ during the day, or getting his 8ish hours of sleep at that time (e.g. a shifted schedule)?

Comment: Hes not being lazy... he just finished college, he has a job, hes being responsible.. unless you really feel the need to pull the "my house my rules" card, then you should just let him make his own choices. It wouldn't hurt to tempt him with activities or try to do something together. As a computer scientist hes headed towards 60 hour work weeks in the industry, let him have a break now if hes still adulting with a job and school etc.

Answer (score 13):

Your son is 19, and about to leave for University.  It's time to stop "enforcing" things for the most part, and start letting him figure out things for himself.  You're not going to have any meaningful control over him three months from now; when he's off at University you won't be able to make sure he sleeps on a certain schedule or, well, anything, in most cases.

Instead, use this summer to let him begin learning his balance and how to work out when he can sleep and when he should not. The optimal answer to this varies by the person - our circadian rhythms are unique to each person, and it's possible that his body is best suited to a 11am-4am schedule rather than a 7am-12am schedule. He'll figure it out; perhaps by messing things up a bit, but isn't it better to mess things up during the summer when it's not as important that he get a good sleep (since he's not in school currently)?

Comment: I agree. He needs to *learn* how to manage himself. It took me a while myself (I was in his boat for a while), but I am thankful now that I have. I needed that experience to build self control and priorities.